# MSD radix sort not workjng

Tags: java

```
    public static void RadixSort(int []a){
    int biggest=0;
    int temp=1;
    int counter;
    int []realArray=new int[a.length];
    int []bucket=new int[a.length];
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i]>biggest){
            biggest=a[i];
        }
    }
    counter=biggest;
    while (counter>10){
        counter=counter/10;
        temp=temp*10;
    }
    RadixSortRecursive(a,temp,a.length,realArray,0,0);
}

private static void RadixSortRecursive(int []a,int pos,int available,int[]realArray,int start,int end){
    int newavailable=0;
    int insert=-1;
    int oldinsert=start;

    int counter=0;
    int [] bucket=new int [a.length]; 
    if (pos>0){
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){

            counter=0;

            newavailable=0;
            for (int j=0;j<available;j++){
                int variable = a[j]/pos;
                variable=variable%10;
                if(variable==i){
                    bucket[counter]=a[j];
                    counter++;
                    newavailable++;
                    insert++;
                }
            }

            if(newavailable==1){
                realArray[start+insert]=bucket[0];


            }else 
            if(newavailable>1){
                RadixSortRecursive(bucket,pos/10,newavailable,realArray,oldinsert,insert);
            }

        }

    }

    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        a[i]=realArray[i];
    }
```

So I've been trying to make an MSD radix sort and I got stuck on my code. My problem is that I want to store all my values in the temporary array ,realArray, then put all the values into my a array at the end. I am able to get the numbers I want but I cannot for the life of me put them in the correct positions of my realArray. I created the start and end parameter in the radix sort just to try to fit them perfectly but it does not work at all. It can work for some cases but not all. Can anyone recommend a fix where I can place everything correctly in my realArray array.